# How to write a data model that needs the properties to be represented as a collection as well as properties

Tags: swift

Let's say you have a data model Car. Car has a number of properties like wheels, engine, windows, etc.
Say you wanted to represent those properties in a parts list, how would you build that into the model?
The challenge is that the properties should be readable and settable through the list items as well as through the properties themselves.

Some thing like

```
car.engine = Engine()
```

should have the same effect as:

```
car.parts["engine"] = Engine()
```

although using a string key is not the right solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `Generic`.

1) First design a `Generic protocol`.

2) Make separate model for wheel,engine and windows and each model must conform to `Protocol` you made in step 1.

3) Then in your `Car` model, make the list of parts as:

let's say you created a protocol named `Parts` and have separate model named `Wheel,Engine and Window`.

```
let carParts:[Parts] = [Wheel(),Engine(),Window()]
```

For setting properties separately, you can iterate over the collection and check the model for which you want to set the properties directly.